# azure membership System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user '{your_username}' in Azure

Tags: c#, azure, membership

I'm trying to deploy an old membership database and asp.net, the issue comes into play when deploying the application to Azure. I'm connected to database in Azure with localhost and when I can run the application locally while still connected to Azure Database(white Listed my IP) I can login in fine.

The issue comes when I publish my website to Azure with all the same settings I did locally. I'm still pointing at the Azure database from before but I get a SQL error when trying to run Membership.ValidateUser  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Login failed for user '{your_username}' in Azure.

I've spend a lot of time trying to figure out what's going. any help would be always be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer to the problem. Connection string needed this Encrypt=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=False; TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;